# Remove HTML Tags But Still Allow Special Characters

Tags: html, mysql

Right I have allowed special characters on MySQL, but now I need to remove HTML tags,

```
 $channelstatus = mysql_real_escape_string('strip_tags', $_POST[channelstatus]) ;
 mysql_query("UPDATE profiles SET  channelstatus='$channelstatus' 
              WHERE username='".$_SESSION['membersusername']."' ");
```

This is the input box

```
<input name="channelstatus" type="text" id="channelstatus" value="<?php

$str = "$channelstatus";

echo "text--->".preg_replace('/(?:<|&lt;)\/?([a-zA-Z]+) *[^<\/]*?(?:>|&gt;)/', '', $str)."\n";

?>" />
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please read the manual: http://php.net/strip_tags

Comment: Why do you need to remove these tags? If it's for security, you don't need to -- just `htmlspecialchars` before output.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it!

```
<input name="channelstatus" type="text" id="channelstatus" value="<?php
echo strip_tags($channelstatus, '');
?>" />
```

Works fine <:D